# How to iterate through files in SAS?

Tags: sas

I would like to iterate through files in a particular folder, and extract substrings of their files names. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
lib dir '.../folder';
#iterate through all files of dir and extract first five letters of file name;
#open files and do some processesing, aka data steps proc steps;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a very common question and a search on SO, or on google will yield many results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I'd point out that "dir" appears to be a misspelt libref, not a folder.  If you are looking for files in a folder, you can use:

```
   %macro get_filenames(location);
    filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
    data filenames(keep=fname);
      handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
      if handle > 0 then do;
        count=dnum(handle);
        do i=1 to count;
          fname=subpad(dread(handle,i),1,5);/* extract first five letters */
          output filenames;
        end;
      end;
      rc=dclose(handle);
    run;
    filename _dir_ clear;
    %mend;

%get_filenames("c:\temp\");
```

If you are looking for *datasets* in a *library*, you can use:

```
proc sql;
create table datasets as
  select substr(memname,1,5) as dataset
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname='LIB'; /* must be uppercase */
```

either approach will produce a dataset of 'files' which can be subsequently 'stepped through'..

Comment: Is there a way to read substring of file before a particular delimiter such as _?

Comment: fname=subpad(scan("some_file",1,'_'),1,5);

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the SQL records created by proc sql and do some command on those, e.g. run a proc export for each SAS file in the lib?

Comment: of course - sth like:  data; set datasets; call execute('proc print data='!!dataset!!';run');run;