# Loop over all Excel files within a folder and extract a certain cell of each with SAS

Tags: excel, import, sas

Assume we have a data directory `C:\temp\` which contains hundreds of Excel files, e.g. `isin47.xls` and `isin11.xls`. Of each Excel file I want to extract the value of cell `$E$16` and create a long table `result` which would look as follows, given the files had `299792458` and `662607004` as value in that cell, respectively.

```
isin   value_euro
47     299792458
11     662607004
```

**How do I do this most efficiently in SAS?**

My idea so far is to the following algorithm:

1. Loop over all files in a directory and create a table `myExcels` with all names, see [How to iterate through files in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886069/how-to-iterate-through-files-in-sas)
2. Loop over `myExcels` and import each of them with code something like

```
proc import
   datafile="C:\temp\isin47.xls"
   dbms=excelcs
   out=data_current_isin
   replace;
run;

proc sql;
   select Value_found_in_E_1 into: value trimmed
   from data_current_isin 
   where Value_found_in_D_1 = "Value_found_in_D_13";
quit;

%put ISIN 47 has value of &value. Euro;
```

3. Collect all `&value.` in the table `results`.

This approach has the problem, that it relies on values in Excel-cells `$D$1`, `$E$1` and `$D$13` which is in general not the case, unless I write a VBA macro to populate the cells (which I want to avoid in favor of a pure SAS solution).

Looking forward to any comments or suggestions.

**PS @allOutsideFinance:** The [ISIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) uniquely defines a financial asset.

Comment: I just found https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2018/06/21/read-excel-range/ which seems to allow me to import custom ranges (and thus also single cells). However, this method uses `dbms=xlsx` which I was told by colleagues to avoid. I am now trying to understand why I should be using `dbms=excelcs` in my current project.

Comment: The `RANGE=` statement of PROC IMPORT works with the `DBMS=XLS` source. What did you try?  How did you specify the range?

Comment: I will keep trying a bit more and show more code in the next few hours...

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/353374a5d8ea4f0c89ce5d80a47f4a4c or this one https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a single cell from an XLS file use a RANGE of just the single cell.  Make sure to also tell IMPORT not to look for variable names.

```
proc import datafile='c:\downloads\test_import.xls' dbms=xls
  out=cell replace
;
  getnames=NO;
  range='$B2:B2';
run;
```

Then it is just a matter or appending that observation to your aggregate dataset.

Might be easiest to create a macro that takes as input the file name to read.

```
%macro read_one(filename);
proc import datafile="&filename"  dbms=xls
  out=cell replace
;
  getnames=NO;
  range='$B2:B2';
run;
proc sql;
   insert into want(filename,value_euro)
     select  "&filename",B from cell
   ;
quit;
%mend;
```

Then you can use your list of files to generate calls to the macro.
First setup an empty file to receive the records.

```
data want;
   length filename $256 value_euro 8 ;
   stop;
run;
```

Then use a data step and generate one call to the macro per file.  You could use CALL EXECUTE for example.

```
data _null_;
   set filelist ;
   call execute(cats('%nrstr(%read_one)(',filename,')'));
run;
```

Comment: That's what I figure out in the meantime. I am still struggling with the aggregation though. I am unsure how to do the aggregation step. I suppose global variables can be avoided...

Comment: It's really an accumulation (or accretion) data set.  @Tom has a data set `want` gathering each value via the `insert into` SQL statement.